# magento model correct placement of methods

Tags: model, magento-1.7, magento

My question is about the correct use and code placement inside the `model` tree of directories. I've been reading a lot but can't get to a conclusion. Here are some of the links I've checked:

- [SQL to Magento model understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169169/sql-to-magento-model-understanding)
- [Magento Models and ORM Basics](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm)
- [Varien Data Collections](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections)
- And several posts on this site [codemagento.com](http://codemagento.com/)

I have a couple of tables and their corresponding models with resources and collection like:

```
magento
.
.
Model
  ├───Resource 
  │      ├─ first_model
  │      │           └─ collection.php
  │      ├─ second_model
  │      │           └─ collection.php
  │      ├─ first_model.php
  │      └─ second_model.php
  ├─ first_model.php
  └─ second_model.php
```

So, my question: I want to know where do I must write my methods. On the php files located on the *Model* folder, on the php files inside the *Resource* folder or inside the *collection.php* file?. I'm looking into different plugins I've installed to find a pattern but I do not understand exactly what to put where. Maybe is trivial, following some pattern but no way I can discover it or find it by googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be several opinions on this matter and I'm not sure that mine is the right one. But since at the moment no one has given their answer yet, I guess even such opinion is better than none.

So for most of the models you have 3 model classes. For example, let us pretend that you have a blog extension and we are talking about model Article:

1. *Collection* (class **Yaroslav_Blog_Model_Resource_Article_Collection**)
   The easiest to describe. You should put here all methods that are supposed to work with multiple articles, especially its data in SQL tables. E.g.: method to sort articles by date, or other method to filter them by author and so on.
2. *Resource Model* (class **Yaroslav_Blog_Model_Resource_Article**)
   This model works with single article's SQL data. For example, method to check that article url key is unique or something like that. Anything, that works with data on SQL level.
3. *Main Model* (class **Yaroslav_Blog_Model_Article**).
   To put it simply, you put here everything else. This model is the highest layer of abstraction and its duty is business logic. You wrote a method, which generates RSS feed with articles? Its place is here (or maybe in a controller). A method to write some kind of log of this article's readers? Here again.

So to put it simply: **unless you are working with SQL queries directly, place your methods in the main model**. I hope it made sense.